# Module not found: Can't resolve 'color'

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have the following `package.json` for my React project.

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fluentui/react": "^8.33.0",
    "@handsontable/react": "^9.0.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.8",
    "@microsoft/office-js-helpers": "^1.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/react-stripe-elements": "^6.0.4",
    "@uifabric/react-cards": "^0.109.49",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "color": "^3.1.2",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "^3.3.1",
    "cross-storage": "^1.0.0",
    "dva": "^2.4.1",
    "dva-model-creator": "^0.4.3",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "handsontable": "^9.0.2",
    "highcharts": "^7.0.3",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.31.1",
    "monaco-languageclient": "^0.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-core": "^11.0.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.105.4",
    "query-string": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-meta-tags": "^1.0.1",
    "react-monaco-editor": "^0.35.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "yup": "^0.28.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3000 react-app-rewired start",
    "start:https": "HTTPS=true  react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8096 build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/color": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/cross-storage": "^0.8.29",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.5",
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.92",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/yup": "^0.26.33",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

`sudo PORT=8000 HTTPS=true ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start` returns me the following error, could anyone help?

```
Failed to compile.

./src/theme.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'color' in '/Users/SoftTimur/Submission/20220114/10Studio/frontend/src'
```

Comment: It's hard to help without sharing the contents of `theme.tsx` with us.

Comment: Since seems that you are using `react-app-rewired` but you are executing your command with `react-scripts`, the issue can be caused by this. Avoid doing `sudo` stuff too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `color` package, make sure that you are importing the package on `theme.tsx`